# Can we annotate a variable in Python while avoiding runtime type erasure of annotation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, python-3.8, type-hinting

I have been reading about this topic and my understanding is that if we annotate a parameter, Python does not erase the annotations in runtime. So in this example:

```
def f(x:int):
    return x
```

the fact that x is in an integer is still preserved in runtime.
By contrast, if we have:

```
def f():
    y :int ; y=5 
    return y
```

Then  `y :int` is not preserved. Is there anyway to declare types in Python for assignment statements such that annotations are preserved in runtime?

EDIT:

what I mean is is the following:

```
class A:
    def f(self,x:int):
        y :int ; y=5
        return (x,y)

print(typing.get_type_hints(A.f))
```

the result is:

```
{'x': <class 'int'>}
```

so we are only able to recover the parameter types but `y:int` has been erased

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: What do you mean by "the fact that x is in an integer is still preserved in runtime"? I am aware of no such thing, except in `f.__annotations__` itself.

Comment: Can you clarify how you would expect to access these annotations? For example, given ``def f(ytype): y: ytype = ytype(); return y`` how would you recover the annotation, ``ytype`` is only defined for a specific invocation of ``f``.

Comment: Note that at global/class scope, ``y: int = 5`` does create an accessible annotation – in the module's/class' ``__annotations__``. The important part is not statement, but the scope.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi can you please clarify how I would invoke this? if I do print(f().__annotations__) I get that 'int' object has no attribute '__annotations__'. Do I need to define custom types with this attribute potentially?

Comment: @Lana You misunderstood – I'm asking how you think one could possibly recover the annotations. What would be the meaning of any annotation depending on a local name? Annotations inside a function are local just like variables; they are only defined during execution (of which there may be zero, one or multiple at once).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi  edited my question with an example. When I use the function get_type_hints from the typing module, I would have expected {y:int} to be in the dictionary too. Are you saying it does not make sense to have the local variable declaration there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no means to get function-local annotations at runtime. This has been encoded in the initial PEP and not revoked since.

> #### PEP 562 – Syntax for Variable AnnotationsRuntime
>
> ##### [Effects of Type Annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#runtime-effects-of-type-annotations)
>
> Also the value of having annotations available locally does not offset the cost of having to create and populate the annotations dictionary on every function call. Therefore, annotations at function level are not evaluated and not stored.

---

The underlying issue is that function-local annotations can depend on function-local state:

```
def f(y_type):
    y: y_type = y_type() 
    return y
```

This makes "the function-local annotations of `f`" undefined – only the specific call `f(y_type)` has well-defined annotations. As a result, annotations would have to be created anew for each call – this is an expensive overhead for each call and would still not expose annotations on the function object itself.
Since the cost of having function-local annotations is not deemed worth it, they are discarded at runtime.